# Visual Studio Code for PHP - No such file or directory

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm able to execute a PHP script in Dreamweaver (under WAMP) but not Visual Studio Code using the [PHP Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver) extension. I'm trying to move off Dreamweaver. In Visual Studio I have an error when calling the script or its location.

Using Wampserver 3.2.5

```
My Apache httpd.conf
Define INSTALL_DIR c:/wamp64
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
```

test.php in folder C:\wamp64\www\Games\netplaybaseball.com\

```
<?php 
echo "test";
?>
```

Using Visual Studio 1.87.0

```
Settings
Ip: localhost
PHP Path: empty (using $PATH environment variable which is set to C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.16)
Port: 8000
Relative Path: empty
```

I have installed all the necessary extensions to use PHP within Visual Studio.

In Dreamweaver, site setting:

```
Local Site Folder: C:\wamp64\www\Games\netplaybaseball.com\
Web URL: http://localhost/Games/netplaybaseball.com/
```

When executing the code under Dreamweaver (using WAMP), it successfully runs. URL is http://localhost/Games/netplaybaseball.com/test.php

With WAMP still running, when executing test.php in Visual Studio, I get this Output:

```
[Sun Mar  3 11:31:44 2024] PHP 7.4.16 Development Server (http://localhost:80) started
[Sun Mar  3 11:31:44 2024] [::1]:56426 Accepted
[Sun Mar  3 11:31:44 2024] [::1]:56427 Accepted
[Sun Mar 3 18:31:44 2024] [404] /wamp64/www/Games/netplaybaseball.com/test.php - No such file or directory 
[Sun Mar  3 11:31:44 2024] [::1]:56426 [404]: GET /wamp64/www/Games/netplaybaseball.com/test.php - No such file or directory
[Sun Mar  3 11:31:44 2024] [::1]:56426 Closing
[Sun Mar  3 11:33:19 2024] [::1]:56427 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Sun Mar  3 11:33:19 2024] [::1]:56427 Closing
```

The URL is http://localhost/wamp64/www/Games/netplaybaseball.com/test.php, and page displays:

```
Not Found
The requested resource /wamp64/www/Games/netplaybaseball.com/test.php was not found on this server.
```

How do I get Visual Studio to execute the correct location?

I've tried different Visual Studio settings but no luck. Or I'm missing the simple answer.

Comment: Unless it's been added in recent versions, Visual Studio Code does not provide any builtin mechanism to run PHP code. Do you know what third-party extension you're using?

Comment: 1) PHP Debug Adapter for Visual Studio Code, 2) PHP Intelephense, and 3) PHP Server.

Comment: In the PHP Server extension, under FEATURES there are Settings. Its phpserver.port was set to 3000. The PHP Server configuration Server's port number was set to 8000. When I changed it to 3000 all is working now.
I did not realize there was a port setting under the PHP Server extension. All other settings matched the settings in PHP Server configuration (under Visual Studio Settings). Its possible the original PHP Server configuration was set to 3000 (I cannot remember). But when you change one, it does not change the other. When they are equal the script works in the browser.

Comment: Are you saying you've solved it now? It's not very clear from your comment

Comment: Yes. Ensure the same port number is set in PHP Server configuration and PHP Server extension. This seems to be the solution. Not sure if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing PHP Server extension, ensure the port setting is the same number as within Visual Studio Code Settings > User > Extensions > PHP Server configuration. If they are different, your script will not be found.